# UNIX domain socket not closed after close()

Tags: c, sockets, unix, virtualization, qemu

I have a client application communicating with a QEMU process through a QMP Unix domain socket. Sometimes after the client calls close() on the socket connection, 'netstat -ap unix' still shows it in CONNECTED state. I do check the return value of the close() call and it returns successfully with a value of 0, but the connection still seems to be lingering.

Since QMP doesn't really support multiple connections on its socket, all the subsequent calls to connect to the socket fail since they wait indefinitely for the lingering connection to be closed.

Is there a way to make sure from the code that the socket is really closed, and is there a way to force the socket to close?

Comment: It sounds like the QEMU server process has not completely read the contents of the last send(). What happens if you switch to using TCP instead of domain sockets? Is there any difference in behavior?

Comment: The behavior I just described isn't 100% reproducible, and unfortunately using TCP is not an option for me.

Comment: Can we see the output of `netstat -ap` ?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it's pending stuff in the socket buffer, so a read from the socket might close it.

Comment: I use this all the time, so it can be made to work. Do you do a `shutdown` before `close()`? Are you reading back the full amount of data from the command you issued? I might see if I've got some releaseable test code around.

Comment: Actually better still, can you post whatever logic you are using in your QMP client as a little stand-alone C, and see if replicates the problem?

Comment: @abligh I don't call shutdown() before close(). The data is usually fully read from the commands until some close() operation doesn't end up closing the socket, or at least that's what I know.

Comment: @abligh I actually wrote some test code to mock the client's behavior and couldn't reproduce the problem except when I deliberately skipped a call to close() in order to leave a lingering connection. However all the close() calls were successful. 
I checked the client code as well, but I couldn't find any paths that would skip closing the socket, which is why I concluded that some calls to close() don't end up in actually closing the socket immediately.

Comment: I've checked the code I use here (sadly the test code I use just calls the library I can't publish) and I don't use `shutdown` either. In terms of packet discipline, I don't just `write`, `read` and hope to get complete JSON packets through; I do full buffering, and cope with both partial reads and writes. I wonder whether that's your issue.

Comment: @abligh I use send() and recv() as opposed to read() and write(), would that be any different?

Comment: @MohammedGamal I can't see why it should be different, but it wouldn't hurt to swap over.

Comment: `shutdown()` before `close()` won't change anything. Clearly you are missing a close somewhere.

Comment: Check that you're not leaking the fd into another process via `fork()/exec()` or its ilk. use `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)` to ensure that's not the source of the problem.

Comment: ... and see if you have closed all `dup()`ed instances of the fd

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the file descriptor has been `dup`ed, `fork`ed, or leaked.

Call [`shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) on it to close the connection for sure before `close`ing.

Comment: I used to get -EAGAIN whenever I tried connecting to a new socket if another connection is lingering. After I used shutdown(), I could actually connect() to the socket without getting -EAGAIN even if another socket is not close()d

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing the socket from the other end? It's asynchronous, but it gives both sides a chance to ensure socket closure.

You can send a close command through to the listener on the other end and have it recycle the socket. When the socket gets closed, you should end up getting a SIGPIPE. Catch the SIGPIPE and close your end of the socket. If you end up with an EPIPE doing that, then ignore it. That just means you were already notified of the socket closure.

Answer (score -1):

You could just try SO_LINGER  via setsockopt(2) option with a timeout of 0. This way, when you close the socket is forcibly closed, sending a RST instead of going into the FIN/ACK closing behavior.

The purpose of the SO_LINGER option is to control how the socket is shut down when the function close(2) is called. This option applies only to connection-oriented protocols such as TCP.

The default behavior of the kernel is to allow the close(2) function to return immediately to the caller. Any unsent TCP/IP data will be transmitted and delivered if possible, but no guarantee is made. Because the close(2) call returns control immediately to the caller, the application has no way of knowing whether the last bit of data was actually delivered.

The SO_LINGER option can be enabled on the socket, to cause the application to block in the close(2) call until all final data is delivered to the remote end. Furthermore, this assures the caller that both ends have acknowledged a normal socket shutdown. Failing this, the indicated option timeout occurs and an error is returned to the calling application.

One final scenario can be applied, by use of different SO_LINGER option values. If the calling application wants to abort communications immediately, appropriate values can be set in the linger structure. Then, a call to close(2) will initiate an abort of the communication link, discarding all pending data and immediately close the socket.

Comment: It doesn't 'assure callers that both ends have acknowledged a normal shutdown'. It only assure the caller that all pending data has been sent.

Comment: The socket in question is a file-based UNIX domain socket, so I am not really sure if using SO_LINGER should help here.